Power Automate random ServerError 00000007
I'm using power pages which trigger power automate flows.
I'm randomly getting ServerError from all of my flows with no explanation:
Status code 500

{"ErrorCode":"00000007","Message":"ServerError"}

the flows are running with no crash/error and finish successfully.
when I retry the same flow trigger after a few seconds - it runs without error.
Is someone familiar with that error code?

Sounds like you need to raise a ticket with Microsoft. ‍♂️
